# Where does apache store php fatal errors?

Tags: apache, store, php

I am in a situation, where is a little posibility of exceeding php execution time. So my idea was to rewrite message like "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 5 seconds exceeded on line 1" to something more 'fancy'. I am using apache.

Where does apache store these php fatal errors (or php errors in general)?
If so, is there a posibility of rewrting those?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** Note - I know where is the error log, I am asking about the actual error message, or the source of the error message if you want.

Comment: It depends. Normally `/var/log/httpd/php_errors.log`, but it's entirely environment dependant. Use `php.ini`'s `error_log` value to force it to a specific file.

Comment: Error logs topics are already here, this topic is about the actual source of the messages not about the place they are stored in ...

Comment: Well then that's nothing to do with Apache but is instead PHP. Unless you recompile it with changed source, you can't change the error text logged for a Fatal Error.

Comment: You'd have to dig through the PHP source, but it wouldn't surprise me if they were just in a header somewhere as constants.

Comment: I found my particular error, it is located in PHP sources => Zend\zend_execute_API.c , there is a posibility to rewrite timeout message, its a call of a zend_error() function...

Answer (score 1):

What you do want to have a look at is this: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

It lets you set a function to handle the errors, you can catch which error you had and display a customized output depending on it.

also this function might be useful for you too:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

It lets you run a function just before the script ends, even if it died.

Comment: I know these, but its not solving my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your ini settings. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) for the relevant settings, in particular `log_errors`, `error_log` and `display_errors`. If `log_errors` is on, errors are logged to `error_log`.

It also sounds like you're after a custom error handler, this can be achieved using [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my question badly, I ment the actual messages not the output.